# Algorithm to adding specific characters to specific places in a string

Tags: java, string, algorithm

for example I have String: `61109010140000071219812874` and I want to apply algorithm, which will transofmation String in the following way:

`611 09-010-14-000-00-712-19-812-87-4`

as you can see, the point is to select the first three letters of the String, then add a white space, then add two dashes after two characters, then three, then again two characters. Something like: 
`### ##-###-##-###-##-###-##-###`

Only I would like my algorithm to be universal. For example, for a string `6110901` output is: `611 09-01`, for a string `61109010`, output is: `611 09-010`

I tried to use StringBuilder and the addCharAt method, but unfortunately it overwrites my string.

Comment: If you post the actual code that you tried, somebody might be able to point out the errors in it.  If you don't post it, we're  less likely to be able to.

Comment: `str.replaceAll("(...)(..)(...)(..)(...)(..)(...)(..)(...)(..)(.)", "$1 $2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7-$8-$9-$10-$11")`

Comment: Or more strictly: `str = str.replaceAll("^(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d{3})(\\d{2})(\\d)$", "$1 $2-$3-$4-$5-$6-$7-$8-$9-$10-$11");` --- See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/NVeAkV/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above answers in the comments work but if you want a regular loop that builds what you want, this should do the trick:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {

    String str = "61109010140000071219812874";
    String output = "";
    int segment = 2;

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i += segment){

        segment = segment == 3 ? 2 : 3;
        String seg = str.substring(i, Math.min(i + segment, str.length()));
        char next = i == 0 ? ' ' : '-';
        seg += next;
        output += seg;            
    }

    output = output.substring(0, output.length() - 1);
    System.out.println(output);   //611 09-010-14-000-00-712-19-812-87-4

}
```